# Using a SOAP service for creating a weather app client

Tags: java, web-services, soap, weather, weather-api

I am writing a weather app in java and I want to use a web service from the internet. But all I managed to find is `OpenWeatherMap` so I was wondering if there was some kind of a `SOAP` service from where I could use the `.wsdl` file, since I believe that approach would be easier for me.

I am looking to keep things as simple as I can, since it is not a big app. Any propositions are welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to look at web services that expose APIs that you can query for retrieving weather information.
For example https://openweathermap.org/api
I am not a great fan of SOAP services, i prefer to deal with JSON.
You could create a controller for interacting with these APIs, and depending on what you want to have then you create your model and then display the data.
Using a Model View Controller pattern with a simple design maybe the best solution, because if for example APIs change then you should easily modify just the controller.